# results-per-page doesn't work when execute cf events

Tags: json, cloud-foundry

I would like to search cloud foundry cf events and set more events in each page like:

```
cf curl /v2/events?order-direction=asc&page=2&q=type:audit.service_binding.create&results-per-page=**100**
```

But it also report:

```
root@boshcli:~/bin# cf curl /v2/events?order-direction=asc&page=2&q=type:audit.service_binding.create&results-per-page=50
[1] 12215
[2] 12216
[3] 12217
**results-per-page=50: command not found**
[2]-  Done                    page=2
[3]+  Done                    q=type:audit.service_binding.create
```

So I can only use 50 per page.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not including the url in quotes or escaping the ampersand, your shell interprets these symbols and executes the query parameters as separate commands.
Try:

`cf curl "/v2/events?order-direction=asc&page=2&q=type:audit.service_binding.create&results-per-page=50"`